# Pimcore Grid Size Column Data Should Be Searchable and Editable

Tags: php, symfony, extjs, pimcore

In pimcore grid size column data should be searchable and editable (Pimcore default size column is not searchable and editable). I have using below ext js code but still i can't able to get the result,

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) { if (!in_array(this.fields[i].key, ["creationDate", "modificationDate"])) {

    var fieldConfig = this.fields[i];
    var type = fieldConfig.type;
    var key = fieldConfig.key;
    var readerFieldConfig = {name: key};
    // dynamic select returns data + options on cell level
    if ((type == "select" || type == "multiselect") && fieldConfig.layout.optionsProviderClass) {
        if (typeof noBatchColumns != "undefined") {
            if (fieldConfig.layout.dynamicOptions) {
                noBatchColumns.push(key);
            }
        }

        if (type == "select") {
            readerFieldConfig["convert"] = function (key, v, rec) {
                if (v && typeof v.options !== "undefined") {
                    // add an empty option to the beginning of the options array
                    v.options.unshift({value: 'empty', key: 'Empty', searchable: true, clicksToEdit: 1});
                    // split it up and store the options in a separate field
                    rec.set(key + "%options", v.options, {convert: false, dirty: false});
                    return v.value;
                }
                return v;
            }.bind(this, key);
            var readerFieldConfigOptions = {name: key + "%options", persist: false};
            readerFields.push(readerFieldConfigOptions);
        }  
    }

    // Don't add batch options if field has dynamic options
    if (
        !fieldConfig.hasOwnProperty('layout') || typeof (fieldConfig.layout) === 'undefined'
        || !fieldConfig.layout.hasOwnProperty('dynamicOptions')
        || fieldConfig.layout.dynamicOptions !== true
    ) {
        if (pimcore.object.tags[type] && pimcore.object.tags[type].prototype.allowBatchAppend) {
            batchAppendColumns.push(key);
        }
        if (pimcore.object.tags[type] && pimcore.object.tags[type].prototype.allowBatchRemove) {
            batchRemoveColumns.push(key);
        }
    }

    readerFields.push(readerFieldConfig);
}
```

If anyone know the answer let me know